# jquery datepicker is not working in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

jQuery Datepicker is not working in table.. im using jquery datepicker v1.12.1 and datatable version v1.10.20

> Date will come but date not pick, did'nt pick dates.. i just want to show current date in that column using datepicker.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/1gv32nLb/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rcpt_vochDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').on('focus', 'input.tableJ:not(.hasDatepicker)', function() {
    $('.tableJ').datepicker();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Realise*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Real.Date*
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="rcpt_mainrow">
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="br_narrate" placeholder='Some Text here' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="rcptDebit" value="" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />

        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="rcptCredit" placeholder='Credit Amount' data-action="sumCredit" class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="tableCbox" name="tableCheck" value="yes">
          <label class="tableBox" for="tableCbox"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control tableJ" id="rcpt_vochDate" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/1gv32nLb/)**

> i just want to show current **date** in that column using datepicker.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f8r3bo2u/

Answer (score 0):

IN our `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes sir, its working perfectly on fiddle, but in my side not working..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code to add datepicker:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rcpt_vochDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').on('focus', 'input.tableJ:not(.hasDatepicker)', function() {
    $('.tableJ').datepicker();
  });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Realise*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Real.Date*
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="rcpt_mainrow">
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="br_narrate" placeholder='Some Text here' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="rcptDebit" value="" placeholder='Debit Amount' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" readonly />

        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="rcptCredit" placeholder='Credit Amount' data-action="sumCredit" class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="tableCbox" name="tableCheck" value="yes">
          <label class="tableBox" for="tableCbox"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control tableJ" id="rcpt_vochDate" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.

Comment: I've changed my code please try it and that is work properly.

Comment: but bro jquery ui latest version is 1.12.1 and you also using jquery 3.3.1 version with 1.12.1 ui jquery that is shown above code

Comment: yeah! its working bro, but date will open but not pick the dates bro.. if i try to pick any dates its not picking.. thats my recent issues..